# I get an error cannot convert

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have got code:

```
Proxy prox = new Proxy();
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, prox);

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
```

I get an error: Argument 1 cannot convert from OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities to OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions.

Do You know what is the reason of that?

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you're calling the `ChromeDriver` constructor with a `DesiredCapabilities` instance when it seems to require a `ChromeOptions` instance.

Comment: Thank You. It resolves problem. However I cannot SetCapability now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.HttpProxy = "proxy:8080";

var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.Proxy = proxy;

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.at");
```